# Error Mondrian JPivot OLAP com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException: 0

Tags: olap, mondrian

I suddently got an error while running mondrian JPivot but it worked fine.
This is the error:

```
JPivot had an error ...

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException: 0

    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    ........
```

Anyone knows the error and know how to solve it???